# Save inputted data from a bound form to a table

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, saving-data

I'm having trouble saving inputted information from a form to a table on MS Access, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a table : Inventory,
and a bound form to that table : InventoryForm

I want to be able to save the inputted data on my Form to either a query or table, so that i see what parts are being taken by each employee (from 'inventory'). At the moment the form is updating the inventory table, reducing or adding parts as done by the form, but it wont save who took what parts in that table.

Is there a simple way that i can link this form to another table/ query to track the changes made to inventory ?

I have a save button with some VBA that, when pressed, updates the inventory list, but i just want to track the transactions too.

The code is:

```
   Private Sub SaveButton_Click()

   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

   End Sub
```

Any ideas how i could do this? From watching tutorials online most people's info from the form will save directly to the bounded table, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks - Mark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inventory database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287097/inventory-database-design). Probably should not be updating inventory list. Instead, save transaction records and calculate inventory balance.

Comment: I want it to update the inventory list, which it is doing, I'm just struggling to save the transaction records to a table once it is completed by the form.

Comment: Exactly how are you struggling? Bind form to a Transactions table, data entered is committed to table.

Comment: Whichever table form is bound to, likely have to execute INSERT or UPDATE action SQL to get data into other table. Again, better to save transaction records and calculate balance.