# How to design database for stock inventory transactions/movements with additional properties?

Tags: database-design, inventory-management

I am designing a inventory stock-management system.

My current understanding is that it should be similar to bank transactions, in which you take inventory from location A and put it at location B. In that case I would have a transaction table like so:

```
id  
product_id  
amount_of_units
from_location_id    
to_location_id
```

To get the quantities-on-hand, I would run through all transactions and spit the sum for a location. So far so good.

The problem comes with the fact that more than one thing can change at a time. It's status can become `ready` or `waiting`. To track `status`, I have to add 2 columns:

```
id  
product_id
amount_of_units
from_location_id    
to_location_id
from_status_id
to_status_id
```

I have 10 or so properties that can change, and I need to keep history of those. Do I add them all to this table with a `from` and `to` prefix? Or do I have to split those in separate tables: `location_transactions` and `status_transactions`, in which case how would I connect them?

Research:
I read a bunch of questions and [answers](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/what-is-the-best-data-model-for-simple-inventory-tracking.309545/#post-1669341) but they all revolve around simple transaction table or double-entry system. Non contain additional information for the item being transacted or changing properties.

Comment: [Inventory database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287097/inventory-database-design) is one place.

Comment: I read that in the research - it doesn't seem to pose the same questions - `how do you structure the database if you have other properties changing of the inventory`?

Comment: You create separate tables for Product, ProductStatus, and ProductLocation.  If you have seven more properties, you create seven more ProductProperty tables.  ProductStatus has a status indicator and a timestamp.  The structure is similar for all the other property tables.

Comment: Okay, so let's say I import 30 products `waiting` status. I make one record for the transactions table and one record with 30 units that are being `waiting`. If 15 become status `ready` then I make another record in the statusTable, is that correct? But how would I connect them? In other words, If I mark 5 as `broken` how would we say it is from the waiting ones or from the ready ones? There seems to bee the need for interconnectedness somehow...

Comment: You have a Transaction table for that purpose.  Every property change requires a transaction row.  The Product and ProductProperty tables hold the current status.  The ProductProperty tables contain a history based on the older timestamps.  The Transaction table shows the property change.

Comment: So the TransactionTable has a one-to-one with the ProductStatus  and also with the ProductQuality?

Comment: Let me repeat: Every property change requires a transaction row.

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying, I am just trying to wrap my head around your concept. So TransactionTable has `id, amount_of_units, status_id, quality_id`. If I add 30 products i make 3 rows:
`1, 30, null null` then `2, 30, 'related_id_of_status', null` and thirdly `3, 30, null, related_id_of_quality`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably create a Transaction table that looks like this:

```
Transaction
-----------
Transaction ID
Product ID
Units
Prior Status
Current Status
Prior Quality
Current Quality
...
Timestamp
```

From your prior comment example

```
1, 1, 30, null, intake, null, waiting, timestamp
2, 1, 15, null, null, waiting, ready, timestamp
3, 1, 5, null, null, ready, broken, timestamp
```